# React initialize state from api, state is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, initialization, state

```
import request from 'request';
var pdfAnnotations;
request('GET', url_ws).done((res) => {
 if (res.statusCode==200) {
  parseString(res.getBody(),{explicitArray:false}, function (err, result) {
    pdfAnnotations=result['root']['element'];
    console.log(pdfAnnotations);// it's OK values
  });
 }
});
console.log(pdfAnnotations);//display "undefined"//first

class App extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    info: pdfAnnotations//is null
  };
  state: State;
```

I need load state from web api data and state is 'undefined', is posible sync or another way???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the initial value of info to `null`, then load data from server and call `this.setState` to set state in `componentDidMount`

```
import request from 'request';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      info: null
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    request('GET', url_ws).done((res) => {
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        parseString(res.getBody(), { explicitArray: false }, (err, result) => {
          const pdfAnnotations = result['root']['element'];
          this.setState({ info: pdfAnnotations });
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at App.js:90
    at Parser.<anonymous> (parser.js:303)
    at Parser../node_modules/events/events.js.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:81)
    at SAXParser.onclosetag (parser.js:261)
    at emit (sax.js:624)
    at emitNode (sax.js:629)
    at closeTag (sax.js:889)
    at SAXParser.write (sax.js:1436)
    at Parser../node_modules/xml2js/lib/parser.js.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (parser.js:322)
    at Parser.parseString (parser.js:5)